# Translate Plurals in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I have this `strings.xml` file in Android Studio:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">SprachenExperiment</string>
    <string name="welcome_message">Welcome to the LanguageLab.</string>
    <string name="goodbye_message">Goodbye.</string>
    <plurals name="oranges_in_stock">
        <item quantity="zero">No oranges in stock.</item>
        <item quantity="one">One orange in stock.</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d oranges in stock.</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

It gets shown to me in Translation Editor like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Why are the `plurals` elements missing? Do I have to enable the feature or does it simply not exist?